# flexbox mobile first menu issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I have tried to emulate the excellent flexbox tutorials by Wes Bos. I wanted to convert one specific [tutorial](https://youtu.be/0jL1SLSPFbk) he has on responsive flexbox menu. But I wanted my menu to be done with mobile first so I did my media queries with `min-width`.

But I am not able to make it work properly on the default mobile layout. In the menu created by Wes, the li items are stacked upon each other and the social icons at the bottom have `flex:1 1 25%`. But my social icons are also stacked.

On the other breakpoints my layout follows the one that Wes created.

I have set up a [codepen](https://codepen.io/lupis/pen/mEbQoj?editors=1100#0) for my code.

```
.flex-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-nav .social {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}

@media all and (min-width:500px) {

  .flex-nav li {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }

  .flex-nav ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .flex-nav ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:800px) {

  .flex-nav li {
    flex: 3;
  }

  .flex-nav .social {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your default code (no media queries applied):

```
.flex-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-nav .social {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}
```

Yes, you've given each social media icon a `flex-basis: 25%`.

**BUT**, your container is `flex-direction: column`.

So the `flex` rule applied to your social media icons works vertically, not horizontally.

Consider this method instead:

```
.flex-nav ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 100%;     /* sized to fit one item per row */
}

.flex-nav .social {
   flex: 0 0 25%;     /* sized to fit four items per row */
}
```

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgbyJW?editors=1100)

Comment: I actually tried flex: 0 0 100% on li, but I didn't put flex-wrap:wrap on the ul :)
Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a container for the social links so it's more easy (at least for me) structure the menu.
[SEE IN CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/LucasFer/pen/Zyzojj?editors=1100)
Here the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="flex-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item04</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item06</a></li>
    <div class="social-container"> 
      <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class=" fa fa-glass"></i></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class=" fa fa-calendar"></i></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class=" fa fa-cutlery"></i></a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

.flex-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%; /* ADDED */

  }


.flex-nav .social {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
  }
.social-container { //just make it flex container 
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}


  @media all and (min-width:500px) {

    .flex-nav li {
      flex: 1 1 50%;
    }

    .flex-nav ul {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .flex-nav ul {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  }

  @media all and (min-width:800px) {

    .flex-nav li {
      flex: 1;
    }

    .flex-nav .social {
      /*flex: 1;*/
    }

    .social-container {
      flex: 2; /* set the value as many as you want */
    }
    .flex-nav ul { //change the direction
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: no-wrap;

    }
  }
```